# Byacc Conflicts

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, yacc, conflict

I'm creating a byacc program to parse some input, and I'm having trouble resolving shift/reduce conflicts, in this case, how could I tell byac to always shift?

```
    53: shift/reduce conflict (shift 49, reduce 36) on '('
    53: shift/reduce conflict (shift 50, reduce 36) on '['
    53: shift/reduce conflict (shift 51, reduce 36) on '{'
    state 53
        body : start_section . section end_section  (32)
        body : start_section . section  (33)
        body : start_section .  (36)
        body : start_section . end_section  (38)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of conflicts: reduce/reduce and shift/reduce. When any conflict arises it's because the grammar you are creating is ambiguous. Your shift/reduce appears because Byacc doesn't know if it should reduce the rule 'body' and go to state 36 (*like "I found this rule, give me input for the next one!"*) OR if it should shift (consume/accept) another token and continue looking for a rule to accept (*like "I haven't found a complete rule but give me more input, maybe then I will*).

Byacc always produces a unambiguous syntactic parser. How? When a conflict (a doubt) arises it just chooses one. Which one? For reduce/reduce it chooses the first to appear on the file. For a shift/reduce it chooses always the shift, by default. So... it will produce the behavior you want just by default.

Still, it's a good idea to have a unambiguous grammar. For that you'll have to resolve the conflict. That means you'll have to find a way to avoid that indecision of Byacc. I hope someone else can I help you with that, I am no expert. I know you can achieve it by reducing the number of rules and removing empty rules like:

```
A:            /* empty */
 | a
 ;
```